# Determining who is accessing my shared folder?

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2003

I have shared few folders on my Windows 2003 server machine. If I navigate to:

> computer management > system tools > shared folders > shares

I am able to see all the folders shared on that machine with the number of people that are currently accessing them.

I can only tell the total number of people and not who is accessing each shared folder. Is there any way I can tell who is accessing the shared folder?

Comment: See this software solution....http://www.thecodeline.com/wp/products/sharewatcher

Answer (score 3):

Using **Command Promp** via *Admin Mode*, type in `net sessions`. This will how who is accessing your computer system. It will also allow you to end there session. More information is found at Microsoft's TechNet page for [net session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490711.aspx).

Comment: It would be cool to see a scheduled batch file that would email a message whenever someone has an active session.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two other folders in the same place you see the Shares screen, Sessions and Open Files. They will list the users and the specific resources they have open, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here are several window apps that provide alternatives to the native `fsmgmt.msc` applet:

http://dottech.org/11324/4-ways-to-monitor-who-is-accessing-your-shared-foldersfiles/

All of them will most likely require elevated privileges in order to show anything useful on Windows 7.

The easiest way to grant admin rights would be to create a shortcut to the EXE file (CTR+SHITF+Drag) then right-click the shortcut > <kbd>Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Shortcut</kbd> tab > <kbd>Advanced</kbd> > "Run as Administrator".